# Sweet and Short way to replace odd occurence of a space with new line in c#

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a string as follows:

```
string s = "My Name is Vishal.";
```

I would like to get output as follows:

```
My Name
is Vishal.
```

I mean I would like to replace space with new line if occurence of space is a multiple of 2.

Currently I am using code below to do my work:

```
string[] sArray = s.Split(' ');
string x = "";
for (int i=0; i <= sArray.Length - 1; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
        x += sArray[i] + ' ';
    else
        x += sArray[i] + Environment.NewLine;
}
return x;
```

The above code is working fine but I know there will be a good way to do it. Can anybody suggest me a good way?

Comment: Would be better in [CodeReview.SE]?

Comment: If it works why do you want to change it? It can probably be done with a regular expression but if you want to improve this as a learning exercise then pasting someone else's answer in isn't going to help.

Comment: Use a string builder rather than string concatenation and use string parsing to look for spaces rather than doing a split

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [CodeReview.SE]

Comment: @LeeWillis - that's the wrong attitude in my opinion. I've seen a lot code in my time that needs changing, even though it works.

Comment: What do you want to do with special cases like two spaces between "A  B", tab chars, leading and trailing whitespace?

Comment: @Pieter21 I don't want to do anything with two spaces. I just want to replace the even occurence of a space with NewLine.

Comment: @DeeMac - I didn't say don't change it, but there was no clear reason for doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One line, if you insist, although I've broken it up. It uses `Split()` so multiple spaces get treated as one space.

```
string.Join(
    Environment.NewLine,
    s.Split()
        .Select((ss, i) => new { ss, i })
        .GroupBy(
            p => p.i / 2,
            (k, ps) => string.Join(" ", ps.Select(p => p.ss))));
```

Regex alternative. This one treats groups of spaces as a single space, but does not replace them with a single space in the odd case.

```
Regex.Replace(s, "(?<=^((?:[^ ]+ +){2})*[^ ]+ +[^ ]+) +", Environment.NewLine)
```

This one will treat each space in a group of multiple spaces on its own.

```
Regex.Replace(s, "(?<=^((?:[^ ]* ){2})*[^ ]* [^ ]*) ", Environment.NewLine)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not stellar, but it amused me enough to write it down :)

```
string s1 = "My Name is Vishal.";
string s2 = "My Name is not Vishal.";

var input = s1;

var list = input .Split(" ".ToCharArray()).ToList();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

while (list.Any()) {
    var bits = list.Take(2);
    sb.Append(bits.First ());
    if (bits.Count() >1) {
        sb.AppendLine(" " + bits.Last());
        list.RemoveRange(0,2);
    }
    else
        list.RemoveAt(0);
}
var result = sb.ToString();
```

Running with `s1` will give you

> my name
>   is Vishal

Running with `s2` will give you

> my name
>   is not
>   Vishal

Comment: Good answer. But just for replacement of characters in string why should I write these many lines of coide? Can't it be achieved using LINQ?

Comment: It is using linq :) the `Any` and `Take` for example.

Comment: Any and Take are LINQ operators but there might be a way like Where(x => x%2 == 0) or something like that to achieve the required output in just 1 line of code.

Comment: This is why i wrote the above. You basically want to take 2 elements each time, and add a new line. But I couldn't figure out another way. Maybe someone else will :). Maybe Iterators are the way ... dunno. You'll still need to implement the logic for checking out what's up ...

Answer (score 1):

Here's the obligatory LINQ version, not sure if that is more readable:

```
string s = "My Name is Vishal.";
var lineGroups = s.Split()
    .Select((word, index) => new { word, index })
    .GroupBy(x => x.index / 2) // integer division truncates decimal part
    .Select(g => string.Join(" ", g.Select(x => x.word)));
string result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lineGroups);
```